# Trace functions defined by letfn

Tags: clojure

We can use `deftrace` from [tools.trace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.trace#example-usage) in place of `defn` for tracing functions. How to do something similar if the function is defined by `letfn`?

Comment: maybe `(letfn [(foo [a] (trace (inc a)))] (foo 3))` ? even though it is not exactly the same

Comment: It's fairly easy to create a [helper macro](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/c321f010f8451fa98cc6a81a8866a80a) after looking over the source of `deftrace`. I don't see anything in that library that would already accomplish this though.